# Editing two strokes together

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I just watched a video of someone drawing in Illustrator, in order for me to learn how to. It was in fast forward though, so it is hard to see exactly what is done, but I noticed something I want to learn how to do.

They uses the Pen Tool to create a normal stroke. As seen here:

[image]

Then they add a triangle on top of it, so it looks more like a normal stroke of a brush or something.

[image]

As you can see in the second picture - the mouse is pulling one of the anchor points to make the stroke more narrow. That is the effect I want to know how to do. And as you can see in the third image, the whole stroke makes a nicer transition as a stroke:

[image]

Can anyone explain to me how this is done? It is two strokes that he somehow can control using the white mouse in Illustrator (not sure what it is called right now), and when he pulls it closer to the other edge it aligns as you see in the final picture.

Here is the link for the video, these screenshots are taking after 2:40 into the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iI-K2eNAXak&t=168s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no a special trick, they are using the **Direct Selection Tool** to move up the first point, to the left the second point and deleting it after changing the tool with a keyboard shortcut: <kbd>p</kbd> to activate the **Pen Tool** and get the **Delete Anchor Point Tool**.

[image: vector]

Answer (score 1):

These kind of speed drawing videos are practically useless as tutorials. Find a better tutorial.

Anyway, all that seems to be going on is that the stroke has been Expanded to outlines, then the anchors have been edited using the Direct Selection tool (A).

[image]

In the newest version of Illustrator CC, you no longer need to do that.  You can change the stroke width with the Width Tool (Shift+W). There's no need to expand to outlines.

For example

[image]